# Need help on how to Http Get request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, get, request

I need to call the API to get the data. Here is the current implementation.

```
return $.get(API_URL)
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
    }, function (response) {
        return response.data;
    });
```

And when i console log value of the response. Have this.

```
console.log(response.data);
Output: [object Object]
```

When I check the Network->Response:

```
JSON
  Data
    0: Object
    1: Object
  Success: True
```

I need to count the number of object in the response. What should I do?

Comment: response.length ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var responseData = JSON.parse(response.data.data)
```

this should give you an object with actual data

and then to count properties of that object with just vanilla JS (this is a lot easier if you use libs or frameworks with stuff like for each etc)

```
if (!Object.keys) {
Object.keys = function (obj) {
    var keys = [],
        k;
    for (k in obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, k)) {
            keys.push(k);
        }
    }
    return keys;
};
}

var numberOfProperties= Object.keys(obj).length;
```

Or in ES5 compatible environment you could use:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuerys getJSON or explicietly tell that you want to receive something of the content type application/json (jQuery already tries to guess the type so this is should not be necessary).
To get the Object values, regardless of their key values, do this:

```
function getMyObjects(){
  return $.getJSON(API_URL)
  .then(function processMyData(data) {
    // if data is an Object with only indices as keys:
    return Object.values(data);
  })
  .catch(console.log);
}
```

This will give you an Array where you can just use the length property

```
getMyObjects()
  .then(function(theArray){ 
     console.log(theArray.length); 
   })
   .catch(console.log);
```

If you want to do something with the keys, you can use

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key){console.log(key, data[key])});
```

If you have to work with old browsers and without some polyfilling, use a `for-in`-loop, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

More about jQuerys getJSON [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)